# Enable FlatList bouncing iOS behavior for Android

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview, flatlist

I know that the React Native FlatList does support the iOS default over-scroll bouncing.

However, it should be possible to achieve natively the bouncing behavior on Android. RN FlatList unfortunately isn't supporting the property on Android.

Is there a way to add the bouncing effect on Android as well maybe with some packages built on top of the native Android functionality?